# Cannot resolve tsconfig paths

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

My Angular 6 project with TypeScript version "2.7.2" has `tsconfig.json` as

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "paths":{
    "@services/*": ["app/services/*"] 
  }
 }
```

I tried importing a service using the above path

```
 import { AppService } from '@services/app.service';
```

But I'm getting this error on running `ng serve`

> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(20,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@services/app.service'.

P.S.- Without the paths

```
import { AppService } from './services/app.service';
```

is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paths` option is part of `compilerOptions`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths":{
      "@services/*": ["app/services/*"] 
    }
  },
 }
```

Comment: It was that simple. I feel so stupid missing that. Thanks a lot mate.